# Using Brackets as git core.editor - OSX

Tags: git, macos, adobe-brackets

I am trying to set up Brackets as my core editor for Git. When I run `config --list`, Brackets is listed as my `core.editor`.  However, when I run `git commit`, I get the following message:

```
error: cannot run brackets: No such file or directory  
error: unable to start editor 'brackets'  
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant output from `git config --list`? Also, do you have the path to the brackets executable?

Comment: From `git config --list` : `core.editor=brackets`.  Could you explain what you mean by the path to the brackets executable?  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: (Please add that output to the question.) If I recall correctly `core.editor` needs the path to a program it can execute. That is, `brackets` needs to be a command that you could very well type at the Terminal yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git can't find executable 'brackets'. That's because there is no such executable in `PATH`. Assuming you have installed Brackets.app in Applications, set your `core.editor` to `/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets`.

Comment: Thank you!  Now I understand.